# How can I use PartialFunctions to compose my match statements?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, partialfunction

Consider the following:

```
scala> object Currency extends Enumeration {
     |   type Currency = Value
     |   val USD = Value
     |   val GBP = Value
     |   val EUR = Value
     |   val TRY = Value // Turkish lira
     |   val NGN = Value // Nigerian naira
     | }
defined module Currency

scala> import Currency._
import Currency._

scala> val pf: (String) => Option[Currency] = {
     |     case "$" => Some(USD)
     |     case "€" => Some(EUR)
     |     case "£" => Some(GBP)
     |     case "₦" => Some(NGN)
     |     case _ => None
     |   }
pf: (String) => Option[Currency.Currency] = <function1>
```

I thought I'd be able to then do this:

```
scala> "$" match pf
<console>:1: error: '{' expected but identifier found.
       "$" match pf
                 ^
```

But no. Am I missing something basic here? My hope was that my PartialFunction could be used and reused in match statements. Is this not possible?

Comment: Your `pf` isn't a partial function, it's a lifted partial function (i.e. a regular function).  That's not why this doesn't work, but in other contexts it can make a difference.

Comment: @Rex Ok, thanks. But if it's not why it isn't working, do you know what is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to use it as a function, e.g.:

```
pf("$")
```

If you will define `pf` as `PartialFunction[String, Option[String]]` you can also use other useful stuff like `pf.isDefinedAt("x")`.

---

If you will look in **Scala Language Specification** section **8.4 Pattern Matching Expressions**, you will find following syntax:

```
Expr ::= PostfixExpr ‘match’ ‘{’ CaseClauses ‘}’
CaseClauses ::= CaseClause {CaseClause}
CaseClause ::= ‘case’ Pattern [Guard] ‘=>’ Block
```

So as you can see it's impossible to use it as you described, but `pf("$")` acts the same way.

Comment: Ahh, very interesting. I had assumed that match was more of a normal Scala thing that took a `PartialFunction` but that's obviously not the case. Out of curiosity, would you happen to know what that is?

Comment: @pr1001: I agree with you. For me it's also more natural to think about `match` as some kind of library extension rather then built-in expression. But it seems that spec has this separation between mentioned section **8.4** and **8.5 Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions**. Sorry, but I don't know reasons for this (perhaps it's just historical reasons... I'm not sure)

Comment: That was how it worked originally, but it was changed at one point.

Comment: @pr1001: It's funny, because generalized `try-catch-finally` is just added in Scala 2.9. Seems that it makes now exactly what one would expect (so that you can give partial function to the catch and other blocks). Maybe `match` will be also eventually changed :)